# memcpy and ntohl different outputs

Tags: c, networking

I need to copy a structure s1 which is in network byte order to another structure s2 in host byte order

I see that the below two methods give different output. I think method2 is correct way of doing it.
Am I correct ? If yes, i did not understand why different outputs. Probably memcpy is playing a role here ?

```
struct abc
{

  int a;
  int b;
  int c;

} ;

struct abc  s1 = {0x58,0x20,0x30};
struct abc  s2;
```

method1:

```
memcpy (&s2,&s2,sizeof(s1));
/* NOTE I read from s2 itself in ntohl */
s2.a= ntohl(s2.a);
s2.b= ntohl(s2.b);
s2.c= ntohl(s2.c);
printf("a %x b %x c %x\n",s2.a,s2.b,s2.c);
```

method2:

```
/* read directly from s1 */
s2.a= ntohl(s1.a);
s2.b= ntohl(s1.b);
s2.c= ntohl(s1.c);
printf("a %x b %x c %x\n",s2.a,s2.b,s2.c);
```

Comment: I don't think either approach is correct if you intend to do `write(sockfd, (void *)&s2, sizeof(s2));`.  You need to be more precise about your sizes.

Comment: Of course the output is different. `ntohl` converts the byte order from big endian (network byte order) most probably to little endian (host byte order, unless you are on a *very* exotic platform). So changing the numbers is its only purpose. `memcpy` or simple assignment on the other hand, will not change anything in the order.

Comment: As an aside, if you do plan to send things over the network, you should use specific sizes of int (e.g. int32_t) and make the struct packed.

Comment: @trojanfoe: I hope the OP does **not** intend to write a structure which had just been converted to host byte order ...

Comment: `ntohl` is for 32-bit values (`uint32_t`) and `ntohs` is for 16-bit values (`uint16_t`).  Use those types in your code for clarity.  Also, I prefer to have different structures for network-byte-order and host-byte-order data, so you always know what's inside of each, and don't pass the wrong data to a given function.  Also, using `be` for big-endian or `le` for little-endian brings additional clarity, especially in projects with multiple protocols and byte orders.  So, `struct abc_be` can refer to big-endian data, and `struct abc` can refer to host-byte-order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be

```
memcpy (&s2,&s1,sizeof(abc));
```

instead of

```
memcpy (&s2,&s2,sizeof(s1));
```

But given that abc is POD, I don't see any benefit of using memcpy except for the fact it is error prone, you can just write

```
s2 = s1;
```

instead (default assignment operator will work fine since there is no pointers in abc).

Comment: +1 for mentioning that `struct` values are perfectly OK to assign, that seems to be another corner of C that is lesser well-known than I would wish. Should probably mention that this approach is still wrong, though (since there's no ordering translation).

Comment: For the sake of stability/security I'd prefer to **always** pass the size of the destionation block to `memcpy()` as 3rd parameter. One never knows ...